# Create firebase Robo file with Visual Studio

Tags: android, firebase, xamarin, xamarin.android, firebase-test-lab

Is there a way to create the robo file for the firebase test with visual studio (because of Xamarin), or is it just possible with android studio?

Comment: create robo file using android studio for the firebase test, you can take a look :https://mobikul.com/create-roboscript-android-studio-run-firebase/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just a text file in JSON format.  You can create it and edit it with any text editing tool you want.

Answer (score 0):

As Doug already mentioned, you can create and edit a Roboscript in any text editing tool.

As about automatically recording a Roboscript for Firebase Test Lab, as of now, doing it in Android Studio is the only available option.